# Первый экран "улетает" при скролле

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://sponge.com.ua/ как сделать эффект исчезания главного экрана как тут?

Comment: Не прелоадер, а именно этот экран должен уходить наверх https://prnt.sc/s501ug

Answer (score 0):

```js
let img = document.querySelector('img');

setTimeout(() => {
  img.src = "https://i.ibb.co/TL787nR/1586433967272.png";
}, 1000)
```

```css
.a{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/9t6qVKc/image.jpg">
</div>
```